# A twisted riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My faces are different, yet equally plain,
>
> they change their expressions to mess with your brain.
>
> I appear quite distorted, I'm twisted, you see,
>
> when I gain my composure I fill you with glee.
>
> Sensitive to your touches, I change on a whim,
>
> most who come to defeat me don't expect to win.
>
> Many try, many fail, many almost succeed,
>
> but inevitably they're frustrated and leave.
>
> It's a lonely existence, and here's the sad truth,
>
> once you learn how to calm me, I've outlived my use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is:

> a Rubik's cube.

My faces are different, yet equally plain

> Rubik's cube of normal variant has 6 faces, all are initially different but similarly coloured.

they change their expressions to mess with your brain.

> The faces can been shuffled to puzzle us.

I appear quite distorted, I'm twisted, you see,

> It's literally twisted to scramble.

when I gain my composure I fill you with glee.

> The pleasure of solving rubik's cube.

Sensitive to your touches, I change on a whim,

> Its configuration can be changed by touching and twisting.

most who come to defeat me don't expect to win./Many try, many fail, many almost succeed,/but inevitably they're frustrated and leave.

> It's well known as a difficult puzzle.

It's a lonely existence, and here's the sad truth,/once you learn how to calm me, I've outlived my use.

> Once solved and mastered, it's usually of no use.

Comment: Hah, good job. I agree my claim it's outlived its use once you solve it was a bit extreme.

Comment: Cheers for the feedback, I'm a bit new to this whole riddling thing so appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Riddle?

My faces are different, yet equally plain,

> Each line is different, yet they're all confusing.

they change their expressions to mess with your brain.

> You can interpret them in different ways.

I appear quite distorted, I'm twisted, you see,

> It's confusing.

when I gain my composure I fill you with glee.

> When you finally puzzle it out (untangle it), you feel a sense of euphoria.

Sensitive to your touches, I change on a whim,

> You change the interpretation based on your current guess.

most who come to defeat me don't expect to win.

> They don't think they're good! :P

Many try, many fail, many almost succeed,

> Who knows - I could've failed here!

but inevitably they're frustrated and leave.

> They give up and abandon the puzzle

It's a lonely existence, and here's the sad truth,
once you learn how to calm me, I've outlived my use.

> Once you figure out the answer, it's not fun anymore.